# Can MOSS2007 authenticate to other AD's?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Let me explain what I have. I work for a local government and I currently have MOSS2007 Server running on our SBS2003 DC that runs Domain A.

The County recently purchased new servers and has a Server 2008 Standard R2 box that they use as a web server. This box, along with all the other main County servers are on Domain B, and yes there is a trust setup between the 2 domains.

I want to uninstall MOSS off of our server and move it over to the 2008 R2 box, but the question is, If I install Sharepoint on the 2008 R2 box that is on Domain B, can I configure Sharepoint to where still authenticates back to the Domain A AD?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes since Domain A and Domain B trust each other. I don't see any issues with that.